# Apache Last-Modified header with now

Tags: apache, header, httpd.conf

I would like to set the Last-Modified header in Apache so that it will always returns the current date time.

Do you know how and if is possible to achieve that?

```
Header always set Last-Modified "{now} GTM"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [expression with time variables](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#vars).

For example:

```
Header always set Last-Modified "expr=%{TIME_YEAR}-%{TIME_MON}-%{TIME_DAY} %{TIME_HOUR}:%{TIME_MIN}:%{TIME_SEC}"
```

Will add in your response:

```
last-modified: 2022-08-04 08:12:03
```